# Using .htaccess to URL rewrite on windows

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wampserver

I have have turned mod_rewrite on in a windows machine and created .htaccess in the root directory of my website, now after i wrote FAIL in it it gave me an internal server error then i replaced the code with this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

I am trying to remove .php and make friendly URLs, when i am tring to load index without using .php it is giving me a 404 Not found error i have restarted the wamp server several times and the same problem. Can somebody help me here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at your error logs. It should show you what the actual filename is that cannot be found. I'm thinking you're probably rewriting a file /test.php to /test.php.php now.

Comment: This is what i found it's looking inside the www directly
script 'C:/wamp/www/destinations.php' not found or unable to stat

Comment: For removing `.php` it would suffice to use `Options +MultiViews`.

Comment: Can you give me an example it is my first time to use .htaccess files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have changed the .htaccess to this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

and it worked just in case somebody faces the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`. It is unnecessary.

Comment: I did as you said but the problem is it's looking inside c:\wamp\www
Not c:\wamp\www\my_site_folder

Comment: The `RewriteBase` tells the server to go looking for /$1.php on the root of the domain.